# Ordenar y reemplazar posiciones en bd mysql

Tags: mysql, comparaciones

Tengo una tabla con estos valores

```
Juan    5
Pedro   7
Luis    6
```

Quiero reemplazar los números consecutivos que se enumeren del menos al mayor a partir del número 1 es decir un script en php que detecte que en la tabla no hay el número 1 entonces asigne a juan que es el valor menor 5 el número 1,
Vuelvo a preguntar, existe el número 2, entonces asigno al siguiente menor que sería Luis cambiarle el 6 por un 2
Vuelvo a preguntar existe el numero 3 si es no entonces asigno el número a pedro cambio el 7 por el 3

El resultado final sería de la siguiente forma

```
Juan    1
Pedro   3
Luis    2
```

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
foreach($idEventsToChangePosition as $ids) {
    $position = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT position FROM $db_table_name WHERE idSiteEvent = %d AND idBlock = %d", $ids, $idBlock));

    $wpdb->update(
        $db_table_name,
        array('position' => $position - 1),
        array('idBlock' => $idBlock, 'idSiteEvent' => $ids)
    );
}
```

Solamente funciona si las tablas tienen posición desde 1 pero si alguna no tiene la posición 1 no es posible

La tabla contiene dos campos:

```
idSiteEvent     position
Juan            5
Pedro           7
Luis            6
```

Donde debo asignar a estos idSiteEvent números de menos a mayor pero empezando en el 1, es decir el script para mysql en php debe detectar quien es el menor número y cambiarlo por 1 luego el siguiente y así hasta lograr

```
idSiteEvent   position
Juan          1
Luis          2
Pedro         3
```

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo puramente con SQL?¿Has intentado algo? Por favor, muestra algo de código, el esquema de la tabla de base de datos o algo que pueda servir.

Comment: en php hay esta el codigo solo necesito saber que cuando no exista el numero 1 en la posicion vuelve a restar 1 a todos los valores hasta llegar a 1 array('position' => $position - 1), cuando sea 1 alguno de ellos que se detenga la resta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una consulta SQL para ordenar y modificar simultáneamente los indices luce como la siguiente:

```
UPDATE test AS t2 
SET t2.id = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM (SELECT * FROM test) AS t1 
             WHERE t1.id < t2.id) + 1;
```

La estructura es como la siguiente:

```
id  name
8   123
34  Oe23M
1   O5555AM
4   OpenIDM
6   OpenAM
9   OpenDJ
```

Después de ejecutar la consulta:

```
id  name
4   123
6   Oe23M
1   O5555AM
2   OpenIDM
3   OpenAM
5   OpenDJ
```

Puedes ver una prueba en [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f05ca/1/0)

Lo que hace es modificar `id` de la tabla contando todos los que tienen indice menor. Esto quiere decir que si el menor indice es 8, `count` devuelve 0, mas la unidad que se agrega al final (+1), queda como el primer elemento y así sucesivamente. *No te recomiendo usar esta consulta en tiempo real, ya que podría ser demasiado lenta, pero sirve para hacer lo que quieres.*

**PD: NO USES ESTA CONSULTA SIN ANTES RESPALDAR TU BASE DE DATOS, YA QUE ES TU RESPONSABILIDAD.**

Comment: Perfecto ahora bien como inserto esto en este array


$wpdb->update(
                    $db_table_name,
                    array('position' => $position - 1),
                    array('idBlock' => $idBlock,
                          'idSiteEvent' => $ids));

Comment: creo que si solo necesitas ordenar, debes hacer la consulta completa sin parametros.

Answer (score 0):

Alguien me ayuda no puedo por la FK en la tabla productos para relacionar la tabla proveedores.... mando mysql bd

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cursoj2ee`.`productos`;
CREATE TABLE  `cursoj2ee`.`productos` (
  `ID_Producto` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_Provee` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Descripcion` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cantidad` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Precio` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   KEY (`ID_Proovee`)  ACA MI ERROR 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2021 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cursoj2ee`.`proveedores`;
CREATE TABLE  `cursoj2ee`.`proveedores` (
  `ID_Provee` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Fecha_Ingreso` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Domicilio` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Provee`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCR
```

Comment: Esta sección es únicamente para respuestas, por favor lee [answer]. Aprovecha y lee también [ask] para hacer tu propia pregunta para recibir ayuda. Saludos.